# AIR 3.0 NativeWindowRenderMode is not defined

Tags: flash, sdk, air

I'm building an AIR application with Flash Builder 4. in the application descriptor I set the minimum AIR version to 3.0
I'm building against Flex SDK 4.5.1 which I overlayed with the AIR 3.0 SDK

I have this line of code in my app:

```
            var nativeWinOpt:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
            nativeWinOpt.renderMode = NativeWindowRenderMode.GPU;
```

this compiles fine, but when I run it in ADL, I get:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.display::NativeWindowRenderMode is not defined.
```

What's the problem? NativeWindowRenderMode should be available in AIR 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you imported it?

`import flash.display.NativeWindowRenderMode;`

you can also try to simply assign the string as the value instead of using the constant:

`nativeWinOpt.renderMode = "gpu";`

i'll assume your AIR 3 setup is correct since it doesn't seem to be complaining about the `renderMode` property, but you can check to see if AIR 3 is being targeted with:

`trace("AIR Version: " + NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion);`

Comment: yes of course I importet it, as I told, the application compiles just fine. I also tried the "gpu" variant but then I get `Error #1056: Cannot create property renderMode on flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions.` So maybe my AIR 3 setup is wrong. I just downloaded Flex SDK 4.5.1 and extracted it, then extracted AIR 3.0 into it and set this SDK to be used in the compiler settings

Comment: your trace method returns `AIR Version: 3.0.0.4080`

Comment: i also receive `3.0.0.4080` output when tracing the runtime version.  when i trace the native window's render mode of the default window that is created automatically `trace("Native Window Render Mode: " + stage.nativeWindow.renderMode);` it outputs `Native Window Render Mode: auto` so this works on my end.  have you followed this to set guide to setup FP11/AIR3 with Flash Builder?  http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2011/09/20/creating-a-custom-flex-4-5-sdk-to-target-flash-11-and-air-3/